# Proving One Sum is Greater Than Another

Tags: real-analysis

Ok so I'm looking to prove that $$\left|\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\right|\geq|a_1|-\sum_{j=2}^n|a_j|.$$ My first instinct is to try to use the reverse triangle inequality but it does not seem to be working. I know that $$\left|\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\right|\leq\sum_{j=1}^n|a_j|.$$ I just can't see where that fact comes into play. Any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: Can you see that $$\Biggl\lvert \sum_{j = 1}^n a_j \Biggr\rvert \geqslant \lvert a_1\rvert - \Biggl\lvert \sum_{j = 2}^n a_j\Biggr\rvert\,?$$

Comment: We dont know the sign of the $a_j$ so some $a_j$ can be negative. But $|a_j|$ is nonnegative.

Comment: Regarding the current "vote to close", with label *Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.* This does not strike me as a flagrant case of this, does it? (In brief: why so prone to "trigger-happiness" when it comes to voting to close?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Detailed** *(from the basic triangle inequality)*

From the triangle inequality:
$$
\lvert a+ b \rvert \leq \lvert a \rvert+ \lvert b \rvert \tag{1}
$$
you get
$$
\lvert a \rvert = \lvert a+ b - b \rvert \leq \lvert a +b \rvert+ \lvert -b \rvert=\lvert a +b \rvert+ \lvert b \rvert
$$
i.e. the "reverse triangle inequality"
$$
\lvert a \rvert - \lvert b \rvert \leq \lvert a +b \rvert \tag{2}
$$

Now, take $a\stackrel{\rm def}{=} a_1$, $b\stackrel{\rm def}{=} \sum_{j=2}^n a_j$ to obtain
$$
\lvert a_1 \rvert - \left\lvert \sum_{j=2}^n a_j \right\rvert \leq \left\lvert \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \right\rvert \tag{3}
$$
Since by the "regular" triangle inequality, $\left\lvert \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \right\rvert \leq \sum_{j=1}^n \left\lvert a_j \right\rvert$, we finally have:
$$
\lvert a_1 \rvert - \sum_{j=2}^n \left\lvert a_j \right\rvert \leq
\lvert a_1 \rvert - \left\lvert \sum_{j=2}^n a_j \right\rvert \leq \left\lvert \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \right\rvert \tag{4}
$$

Answer (score 1):

This is just a combination of the reverse triangle inequality and the usual triangle inequality.  To keep things straight, let $b=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j$ and $c=\sum_{j=2}^n a_j$.  Then $b=a_1+c$, so by the reverse triangle inequality, $|b|\geq |a_1|-|c|$.  Now you want to use the triangle inequality on the $|c|$ term to finish; I'll let you work out the details.